# s3 amazon domain

Tags: amazon-s3

Hi just began to use s3 amazon services

when i try to access

s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/file.html

i get an error message like that

```
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

but i can access

bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/file.html

how can i access to my files

like this

http://s3.amazonaws.com/1000genomes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmaticly you have to use a region endpoint like US-East-1. It's the server where you have stored your bucket.